# How to resolve the dateTime casting error in MarkLogic import

Tags: marklogic

I am getting this error while casting a value from a XML element into MarkLogic column using a template for the extraction of the data.

> 22/05/12 10:22:17 WARN mapreduce.ContentWriter: Batch 1009629724.0: TDE-INDEX: Error applying template /powerbi/shipment-CBE123.xml to document /powerbi/shipment/CBE00038464N/C:/Users/admin-rp/Documents/Marklogic/ML_With_PowerBI/bi-tools-master/bi-tools-master/power-bi/marklogic_powerbi_tutorial/data/CBE00038464N.xml: TDE-EVALFAILED: Eval for Column POD_ETA_Act_Arr='ns10:ASN/ns10:Schedule/ns5:TransportationUnitHeader/ns5:PrimarytUnit/ns5:TransportUnit/ns5:PortOfDischarge/ns9:ActualArrivalDate' returns XDMP-CAST: (err:FORG0001) Invalid cast: xs:untypedAtomic("") cast as xs:dateTime

The element value for the field `ActualArrivalDate` is like this in the XML file -

```
<ns5:PortOfDischarge>
  <ns9:PortName />
  <ns9:PortCode />
  <ns9:ScheduledArrivalDate xsi:nil="true" />
  <ns9:ActualArrivalDate xsi:nil="true" />
  <ns9:ScheduledDepartureDate xsi:nil="true" />
  <ns9:ActualDepartureDate xsi:nil="true" />
</ns5:PortOfDischarge>
```

And my template form for this filed looks like this -

```
<column>
  <name>POD_ETA_Act_Arr</name>
  <scalar-type>dateTime</scalar-type><val>ns10:ASN/ns10:Schedule/ns5:TransportationUnitHeader/ns5:PrimarytUnit/ns5:TransportUnit/ns5:PortOfDischarge/ns9:ActualArrivalDate</val>
  <nullable>true</nullable>
</column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The casting error:

> XDMP-CAST: (err:FORG0001) Invalid cast: xs:untypedAtomic("") cast as xs:dateTime

is telling you that the untyped atomic value of an empty string `""` cannot be cast to an xs:dateTime.

One way to avoid this might be to adjust the XPath in the template to exclude those that don't have a value. For instance, adding a predicate to ensure that the value is castable as xs:dateTime: `[. castable as xs:dateTime]` or just filtering out elements with empty or whitespace-only values `[normalize-space()]`.

I'm a little surprised that it complains since your `<ns9:ActualArrivalDate xsi:nil="true" />` data element has the `@xsi:nil="true"` and the TDE column has `<nullable>true</nullable>`. I would expect that it would "see" that element as having a null value, rather than an empty string. However, I think you may need to have your schemas loaded into the Schemas database indicating that the particular element can be nillable, or it won't see it as null.

Comment: Thanks, I am ignoring the value for now with this - 
<invalid-values>reject</invalid-values>
I am very new to marklogic and perhaps with time will learn how to control these in a more organised way. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Mads, In your last comment you have added that to avoid the casting error we can import the schemas in the Schemas Database . Will that validate the TDEs against the schema ? How can we validate certain TDEs with the respective schemas. Can you please tell in more details. Thanks

Comment: If you have XML schemas in your Schemas database that declare some element to be `nillable="true"`, then the element will be evaluated as https://docs.marklogic.com/fn.nilled Just having `@xsi:nil="true"` on an instance document does not mean that it will be seen as nilled.

Comment: I can import the XML schemas in my Schemas database , but can I make reference the XSD schema to my TDEs ?